# Program giving inconsistent results and sometimes crashing

Tags: c

I have an assignment to do and this is the partial code of the program. Like, 20% of the time it runs properly, 50% it runs inproperly and 30% of the time it crashes completely and I have no idea why.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
//printf("Type "Show" to show words, type "Add" to enter a word, type "Delete" to delete a word");
char command[10];
char languageChoice[10];
char EnglishWords[][20] = {"Dog", "Table", "Chair"};
int flag = 2;

do
{
printf("\nEnter command(Add, Show, End): ");
scanf("%s", &command);
 
if (strcmp(command, "Add") == 0)
    {
printf("Choose language (English,...): ");
scanf("%s", &languageChoice);
    if (strcmp(languageChoice, "English") == 0)
        {
            //user chose add word in English section
            flag = flag + 1;
            char NewEnglishWord[20];
            printf("Enter new word in English: ");
            scanf(" %s", &NewEnglishWord);
            memcpy(EnglishWords[flag], NewEnglishWord, sizeof(EnglishWords[flag]));
            printf("\nTest: EnglishWords[%d] = %s\n", flag, EnglishWords[flag]);
            
        }
    }

if (strcmp(command, "Delete") == 0)
    {
printf("You entered command Delete.\n");
    }

if (strcmp(command, "Show") == 0)
    {
    printf("English words: \n");
    int i=0;
    for(2==2; i<=flag; i++)
        {
        printf("EnglishWords[%d] = %s, \n", i, EnglishWords[i]);
        }

    }
}
while (strcmp(command, "End") != 0);

printf("Program has ended!");

return 0;
}
```

For example, the input is: "Add->English->Word1->Add->English->Word2->Add->English->Word3"

The expected output is:

```
EnglishWords[0] = Dog,
EnglishWords[1] = Table,
EnglishWords[2] = Chair,
EnglishWords[3] = Word1,
EnglishWords[4] = Word2,
EnglishWords[5] = Word3.
```

But instead EnglishWords[3] looks something like "WordWord3". And thats like 50% of the time... when it doesnt crash.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by using out-of-range of the array `EnglishWords`, so anything is allowed to happen.

Comment: im sorry for the very impolite title @Daniel Walker

Comment: Remove `&` from all the `scanf`s - these are already pointers, so don't need the `&`. Also, what is the purpose of `2==2` in that `for` loop. Have you tried compiling this with some basic compilation flags -- any compiler will warn you about both of these.

Comment: thanks for answer @MikeCAT . any suggestion on how to fix that? as you can probably tell i dont have much experience with C

Comment: Look up tools like `valgrind` and `AddressSanitizer` which will help catch bugs like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array

```
char EnglishWords[][20] = {"Dog", "Table", "Chair"};
```

has only 3 elements, so you must not use (no read nor write) `EnglishWords[3]` and above.

It seems you should allocate the memory dinamically like this:

```
char (*EnglishWords)[20] = malloc(sizeof(*EnglishWords) * 3);
if (EnglishWords == NULL) {
    // malloc() failed
    return 1;
}
strcpy(EnglishWords[0], "Dog");
strcpy(EnglishWords[1], "Table");
strcpy(EnglishWords[2], "Chair");
```

and glow the array on adding elements like this:

```
flag = flag + 1;
char NewEnglishWord[20];

// add this part for re-allocation
char (*NewEnglishWords)[20] = realloc(EnglishWords, sizeof(*EnglishWords) * (flag + 1));
if (NewEnglishWords == NULL) {
    // realloc() failed
    free(EnglishWords);
    return 1;
}
EnglishWords = NewEnglishWords;

printf("Enter new word in English: ");
scanf(" %s", NewEnglishWord);
memcpy(EnglishWords[flag], NewEnglishWord, sizeof(EnglishWords[flag]));
printf("\nTest: EnglishWords[%d] = %s\n", flag, EnglishWords[flag]);
```

Another option is allocating `EnglishWords` statically with enough elements like this:

```
char EnglishWords[10240][20] = {"Dog", "Table", "Chair"};
```

and checking the size not to cause overflow:

```
if (flag + 1 < (int)(sizeof(EnglishWord) / sizeof(*EnglishWord))) {
    flag = flag + 1;
    char NewEnglishWord[20];
    printf("Enter new word in English: ");
    scanf(" %s", NewEnglishWord);
    memcpy(EnglishWords[flag], NewEnglishWord, sizeof(EnglishWords[flag]));
    printf("\nTest: EnglishWords[%d] = %s\n", flag, EnglishWords[flag]);
} else {
    puts("no room left");
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, really appreciate it!

Comment: I ran into a problem. 
` char (*EnglishWords)[20] = malloc(sizeof(*EnglishWords) * 3 ); `
and
` char (*NewEnglishWords)[20] = realloc(EnglishWords, sizeof(*EnglishWords) * (flag + 1)); `

give Error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char (*)[20]' [-fpermissive] 
@MikeCAT

Comment: nevermind @MikeCAT .. it was the compiler program that gave the error. really appreciate the help, i admire people like you

Comment: Hello @MikeCAT , I have an additional question. I used the first suggestion you gave me and it works wonderfully. But I have a hard time understanding it.

Can you please explain to me (a beginner at C):

-this line: `char (*EnglishWords)[20] = malloc(sizeof(*EnglishWords) * 3);` .

How does it work, why do we initialise a pointer and how is the array initialised in this line of code? Why do we multiply sizeof(*EnglishWords) by 3?